# Mud fly direction on wheel spinning

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotation

[image]

A Spins one wheel of an upturned bicycle, mud particles fly off. What will be the direction of the movement of the mud if it comes out at point 'X'?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Commenters, please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.